# Agregar un código que procese cuando se abre la ventana a un JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

yo no sé programar en Java y estoy siguiendo como una especie de guía pero el que hizo esa guía escribió el código con muchos errores y me ha tocado arreglarlo buscando en foros y cosas así. El detalle es que se creó un `JFrame` y explicó el código a colocar pero el `JFrame` tiene tantas funciones que no especificó en que parte exactamente va el código. Es este

```
persona p;

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)    {
                //Obejeto para almacenar datos
                Object[][] dtPer;
                String[] columNames = {"id", "Nombre", "Ap. Paterno", "Ap. Materno", "E-Mail"};
                //se utiliza la función
                dtPer = p.getDatos();
                //Se colocan los datos en la tabla
                DefaultTableModel datos = new DefaultTableModel(dtPer, columNames);
                tabla.setModel(datos);
    }
```

En qué parte exactamente va? y está pasando parámetros y tampoco especificó para que son ya que `evt` no se está usando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según puedo ver en el código que compartes, estas accediendo a un evento del JFrame que se ejecuta únicamente cuando este se inicia, para acceder a este evento debes: Click derecho en Jframe >> Events >> Window >> WindowOpened (Añado imagen)
[image: Acceder a windowOpened]

Para mostrar una vista desde el main debes importar el paquete y la clase de la vista:`import paquete.clase;`

Para mostrarlo debes crear un objeto de la vista y hacer uso de la funcion setVisible(), o simplemente definirla como vista principal.